# Kicking off processing after opening an NSDocument

Tags: cocoa

Is there a method to override that lets me perform work on my NSDocument before it displays it's window? Ideally, I'd like the option to not display the window and even close the document before it's displayed to the user. I know this sounds odd, but the document is "sometimes" more of a command file than a editable document that the user works on.

I was able to hide the window by overriding `showWindows` (not calling `[super showWindows]`) but when the window isn't visible, saving the document hangs on Lion. Also, I've tried `[self close]` within the `readFromData` but that doesn't appear to work.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do this is to create and use your own NSDocumentController subclass.

Helpful docs: [Document Opening Message Flow section of Document-Based Applications Overview](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Documents/Articles/ObjectInteractions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003196-SW9) and [Creating a Subclass of NSDocumentController](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Documents/Tasks/SubclassController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000953-BCIJGBIF) (same doc).